# How to "programmatically" integrate diff tool with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, winmerge

Is there a way to "programatically" integrate a diff tool (like WinDiff and WinMerge) with Visual Studio 2010? These files are not the files found at Solution Explorer.

The program would have to search and store in the List the files found from certain directory, and then compare the files with same names recursively.

Comment: What exactly are yu trying to achieve?  Do you just want to identify that files, or the text in files, differs, or do you actually want WinMerge to appear for each file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can gather, you're looking for the TFS [`Difference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.difference%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class.  Here's an example of how to use it:

```
string f1 = @"file1.cs";
string f2 = @"f2.cs";

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.DiffOptions options = new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.DiffOptions();
options.Recursive = true;
options.StreamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
options.UseThirdPartyTool = true;
options.OutputType = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.DiffOutputType.Unified;            

var diff = Difference.DiffFiles(
            f1, FileType.Detect(f1, null),
            f2, FileType.Detect(f2, null),
            options);

while (diff != null)
{
    // Do whatever it is that you want to do here            
    diff = diff.Next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look whether this extension is what you need: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dace3633-0b51-4629-85d4-c59cdce5bb3b?SRC=Featured

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to automate comparing files in winmerge or windiff and using C# language?

Comment: If you're about to launch windiff in your code, you may call it by starting a new process, look at [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I would like to compare the files without actually executing WinDiff. I haven't found a solution for that... maybe the best way for me is to just code it using the method `ReadAllText` then.